# share storage account on different subscription and location

Tags: azure, mount, azure-storage-files

I successfully mounted a Azure File Storage to a VM which is inside the same subscription and location. Now I cloned this VM to a new subscription and another location - so my new machine is exactly the same except of subscription and location. When I run the same command for mounting the same file storage:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //MYACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net/MY/FOLDER /MY/LOCAL/FOLDER/ -o vers=3.0,username=USER,password=ACCESSKEY,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

then I get

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I think it has something to do with the different subscription and location, because in the portal when I click on `connect` in my file storage it is said:

```
To connect to this file share, run this command from any Windows virtual machine on the same subscription and location:
```

So is there any possibility to connect to my file storage from within another subscription and location?

Comment: What is the windows server version you are using on your VM?

Comment: It's a Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I just posted that sentence from the portal because I think it's a hint for a certain limitation - but I can't find "official" limitations regarding file storage connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the SMB 3.0 protocol to connect outside of that Azure region. This page says it's not supported on Linux:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/

> Note that since the Linux SMB client doesn’t yet support encryption, mounting a file share from Linux still requires the client to be in the same Azure region as the file share. However, encryption support for Linux is on the roadmap of Linux developers responsible for SMB functionality.

Edit: There is an update on Ubuntu [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-file-storage-on-premises-access-for-ubuntu/).